# Condition based on multiple column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

My objectif is to change column name of a dataframe. To do that i have a lookup file which map le old names and new names.
I also have a dataframe with olds data.

I need to change columns names based on the lookup file.

Data df :

| column1 | column2 | column3 | column4 | column5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| yes | no | 1 | 0 | TOTO |

Lookup df :

| alias1 | alias2 | type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| column1 | alias1 | value |
| column2 | alias2 | value |
| column3 | alias3 | mode |
| column4 | alias4 | difficulty |
| column5 | alias5 | value |

For the moment i want to create 3 conditions based on Lookup file columns `alias1` and `type`

I can not enter in my finals if condition, and i do not understand why. Here is my code :

````
for data in data_df : 

    if(data in lookup_df['aliasv1'].values):

        if('valeur' in lookup_df['type']):
            print(data)

        if('mode' in lookup_df['type']):
            print(data)

        if('penibilite' in lookup_df['type']):
            print(data)```

Thank you for your help
````

Comment: Question seems unclear to me. Can you please elaborate more? Also  please make sure to include your expected output.

Comment: Do you have a typo in the instruction ```lookup_df['aliasv1'].values```?  Should it be ```lookup_df['alias1'].values```?